# jquery tokeninput don't showing data on the h:inputtext while editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, seam, jquery-tokeninput

I use seam framework and i want to integrate [tokeninput autocomplete plugin](https://raw.github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js) in my project.

I succeeded to make the integration and the data is saved on the database, but the problem is when I submit the form on validation the data is lostfrom the `h:inputtext`, also while editing the input text is empty.

```
<ui:define name="head">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery/token-input.css" media="screen"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery/token-input-mac.css" media="screen"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery/token-input-facebook.css" media="screen"/>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("div.permiss input").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", {
                     theme: "facebook",
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="body">
    <body>
        <h:form id="permission" styleClass="edit">
            <rich:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">#{permissionHome.managed ? 'Edit' : 'Add'} Permission</f:facet>
                <s:decorate id="nomPermissionField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                    <ui:define name="label">Nom permission</ui:define>
                    <div class="permiss">       
                        <h:inputText  id="nomPermission" required="true" value="#{permissionHome.instance.nom}"/>
                    </div>
                </s:decorate>

                <s:decorate id="targetPermissionField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                    <ui:define name="label">Target permission</ui:define>
                    <div class="voici1" >
                        <h:inputText id="targetPermission" cols="80" rows="10" required="true" value="#{permissionHome.instance.target}"/>
                    </div>
                </s:decorate>

                <s:decorate id="DiscriminatorPermissionField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                    <ui:define name="label">Discriminator permission</ui:define>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="selectdisc" value="#{permissionHome.instance.discriminator}" required="true">
                        <f:selectItem id="si0" itemLabel=" " itemValue=" "/>
                        <f:selectItem id="si1" itemLabel="role" itemValue="role"/>
                        <f:selectItem id="si2" itemLabel="user" itemValue="user" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </s:decorate>

                <div style="clear:both">
                    <span class="required">*</span>
                    required fields
                </div>
            </rich:panel>

            <div class="actionButtons">
                <h:commandButton id="save" value="Savee" action="#{permissionHome.persist}"
                     oncomplete="javascript:window.parent.location.reload(true);" 
                     disabled="#{!permissionHome.wired}" 
                     rendered="#{!permissionHome.managed}"/>

                <h:commandButton id="update" value="Save" action="#{permissionHome.update}" rendered="#{permissionHome.managed}"/>
                <h:commandButton id="delete" value="Delete" action="#{permissionHome.remove}" immediate="true" rendered="#{permissionHome.managed}"/>

                <s:button id="cancelEdit" value="Cancel" propagation="end" view="/Permission.xhtml" rendered="#{permissionHome.managed}"/>

                <s:button id="cancelAdd" value="Cancel" propagation="end" view="/#{empty permissionFrom ? 'PermissionList' : permissionFrom}.xhtml" rendered="#{!permissionHome.managed}"/>    
            </div>
        </h:form>    
    </body>
</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe remove the comma from the following line?

theme: "facebook",